# Filling empty python dataframe using loops

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Lets say I want to create and fill an empty dataframe with values from a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

years = [2013, 2014, 2015]
dn=pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Incidents': [ 'C', 'B','A'],
                 year: [1, 1, 1 ],
                }).set_index('Incidents')
    print (df1)
    dn=dn.append(df1, ignore_index = False)
```

The append gives a diagonal matrix even when ignore index is false:

```
>>> dn
       2013  2014  2015
Incidents                  
C             1   NaN   NaN
B             1   NaN   NaN
A             1   NaN   NaN
C           NaN     1   NaN
B           NaN     1   NaN
A           NaN     1   NaN
C           NaN   NaN     1
B           NaN   NaN     1
A           NaN   NaN     1

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

It should look like this:

```
>>> dn
       2013  2014  2015
Incidents                  
C             1   1   1
B             1   1   1
A             1   1   1

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Is there a better way of doing this? and is there a way to fix the append?

I have pandas version '0.13.1-557-g300610e'

Comment: do you need to  have incidents in this way or a normal dataframe is fine for you (I mean just a matrix with names)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

years = [2013, 2014, 2015]
dn = []
for year in years:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Incidents': [ 'C', 'B','A'],
                 year: [1, 1, 1 ],
                }).set_index('Incidents')
    dn.append(df1)
dn = pd.concat(dn, axis=1)
print(dn)
```

yields

```
           2013  2014  2015
Incidents                  
C             1     1     1
B             1     1     1
A             1     1     1
```

---

Note that calling `pd.concat` *once* outside the loop is more time-efficient
than calling `pd.concat` with each iteration of the loop.

Each time you call `pd.concat` new space is allocated for a new DataFrame, and
all the data from each component DataFrame is copied into the new DataFrame.  If
you call `pd.concat` from within the for-loop then you end up doing on the order
of `n**2` copies, where `n` is the number of years.

If you accumulate the partial DataFrames in a list and call `pd.concat` once
outside the list, then Pandas only needs to perform `n` copies to make `dn`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you should avoid to add line by line to the dataframe due to speed issue

What I usually do is:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

for i in range(n):
   compute value v1
   compute value v2
   l1.append(v1)
   l2.append(v2)

d = pd.DataFrame()
d['l1'] = l1
d['l2'] = l2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you tell me why we should avoid adding  rows line by line?