# Appending to an empty data frame in Pandas using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am writing because I am having an issue with a for loop which fills a dataframe when it is empty. Unfortunately, the posts [Filling empty python dataframe using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910089/filling-empty-python-dataframe-using-loops), [Appending to an empty data frame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597265/appending-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-pandas), [Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, then filling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it) did not help me to solve it.

My attempt aims, first, at finding the empty dataframes in the list "listDataframe" and then, wants to fill them with some chosen columns. I believe my code is clearer than my explanation. What I can't do is to save the new dataframe using its original name. Here my attempt:

```
for k,j in zip(listOwner,listDataframe):
for y in j:
    if y.empty:
        data = pd.DataFrame({"Event Date": list_test_2, "Site Group Name" : k, "Impressions" : 0})
        y = pd.concat([data,y])
        #y = y.append(data)
```

where "listOwner", "listDataframe" and "list_test_2" are, respectively, given by:

```
listOwner = ['OWNER ONE', 'OWNER TWO', 'OWNER THREE', 'OWNER FOUR']
listDataframe = [df_a,df_b,df_c,df_d]
```

with

```
df_a = [df_ap_1, df_di_1, df_er_diret_1, df_er_s_1]
df_b = [df_ap_2, df_di_2, df_er_diret_2, df_er_s_2]
df_c = [df_ap_3, df_di_3, df_er_diret_3, df_er_s_3]
df_d = [df_ap_4, df_di_4, df_er_diret_4, df_er_s_4]
```

and

```
list_test_2 = []
for i in range(1,8):
    f = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=i)).date()
    list_test_2.append(datetime.combine(f, datetime.min.time()))
```

The empty dataframe were df_ap_1 and df_ap_3. After running the above lines (using both concat and append) if I call these two dataframes they are still empty. Any idea why that happens and how to overcome this issue?

**UPDATE**

In order to avoid both append and concat, I tried to use the coming attempt (again with no success).

```
for k,j in zip(listOwner,listDataframe):
    for y in j:
        if y.empty:
            y = pd.DataFrame({"Event Date": list_test_2, "Site Group Name" : k, "Impressions" : 0})
```

The two desired result should be:

[image]

where the first dataframe should be called `df_ap_1` while the second one  `df_ap_3`.

Thanks in advance.

Drigo

Comment: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Comment: What is list_test_2? Also, that's a lot of dataframes. Any chance you could combine all 16 of your data frames into one big data frame? Maybe you could do so by adding a column that would have value of 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd' and then also a column that would have a value of 'ap', 'di', 'er_direct' or 'er_s'.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have updated my attempt. I had forgotten the definition of list_test_2. Actually they are a lot of dataframes but with only fews rows each.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Event Date', 'Site Group Name', 'Impressions']
df_ap_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns) #empty dataframe
df_di_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns) #empty dataframe
df_ap_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Event Date':[1], 'Site Group Name':[2], 'Impressions': [3]}) #non-empty dataframe
df_di_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns) #empty dataframe

df_a = [df_ap_1, df_di_1]
df_b = [df_ap_2, df_di_2]
listDataframe = [df_a,df_b]

list_test_2 = 'foo'
listOwner = ['OWNER ONE', 'OWNER TWO']

def appendOwner(df, owner, list_test_2):
    #appends a row to a dataframe for each row in listOwner
    new_row = {'Event Date': list_test_2,
               'Site Group Name': owner,
               'Impressions': 0,
               }
    df.loc[len(df)] = new_row

for owner, dfList in zip(listOwner, listDataframe):
    for df in dfList:
        if df.empty:
            appendOwner(df, owner, list_test_2)

print(listDataframe)
```

You can use the `appendOwner` function to append the rows from listOwner to an empty dataframe.

Comment: Hi @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero, thanks for your effort. I am afraid this is not what I was looking for. Please see the photo I have just attached to this post. I would like the owner to depend on the listDataframe. That's why I used zip. Depending where the empty dataframe is in the listDataframe, it has a different owner. I hope I explained myself. :)

Comment: I see. I edited the code. I think it is what you want.